# How to import html and css files in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to import the folder that contains css and html. Is it possible execute these files in ruby on rails?

Comment: What do you mean by import? Uploading via a webpage at runtime or including into the application at development time? The first would be complex, the later might be achievable by just placing the files in the `public` folder of the application.

Comment: Hi @ALABYU - thanks for joining SO community. Please be more specific, can you show us your code? Have you read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may be able to read those files if you put them in the ```public``` directory.

Comment: what i mean is to put another html as a page in rails

Answer (score 0):

1. javascripts, stylesheets

   1) use `app/assets/javascripts` or `app/assets/stylesheers`

   - you don't have to define into .html.erb like `<link rel="..." src="...">` or `<script src="...">`
   - it dosen't effect `browser cache`

   2) upload `public` directory

   - but, not recommand
   - you have to define into .html.erb like `<link rel="..." src="...">` or `<script src="...">`
   - it dose effect `browser cache`
2. HTML

   just use `public` directory